# Purpose of Advice.withCustomMapping().bind(...)

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I am trying to understand the purpose and use of `Advice.withCustomMapping().bind(...)`, to see if it can help my use-case.

Reading the javadoc for `Advice.withCustomMapping()`:

> Allows for the configuration of custom annotations that are then bound to a dynamically computed, constant value.

Here is the use-case to which I am trying to apply this pattern:

```java
public @interface Name {
}
```

```java
public abstract class AgentRule {
  private final String className = getClass().getName();

  public final Advice.WithCustomMapping advice() {
    return Advice.withCustomMapping().bind(Name.class, className);
  }

  public static boolean isEnabled(final String className, final String origin) {
    ...
  }

  public abstract Iterable<? extends AgentBuilder> buildAgent(AgentBuilder builder) throws Exception;
}
```

```java
public class ServletContextAgentRule extends AgentRule {
  public static boolean filterAdded = false;

  @Override
  public Iterable<? extends AgentBuilder> buildAgent(final AgentBuilder builder) throws Exception {
    return Arrays.asList(builder
      .type(named("org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler"))
      .transform(new Transformer() {
        @Override
        public Builder<?> transform(final Builder<?> builder, final TypeDescription typeDescription, final ClassLoader classLoader, final JavaModule module) {
          return builder.visit(advice().to(JettyAdvice.class).on(isConstructor()));
        }})
.type(not(isInterface()).and(hasSuperType(named("javax.servlet.ServletContext"))
        // Jetty is handled separately due to the (otherwise) need for tracking state of the ServletContext
      .transform(new Transformer() {
        @Override
        public Builder<?> transform(final Builder<?> builder, final TypeDescription typeDescription, final ClassLoader classLoader, final JavaModule module) {
          return builder.visit(advice().to(ServletContextAdvice.class).on(isConstructor()));
        }}));
  }

  public static class JettyAdvice {
    @Advice.OnMethodExit
    public static void exit(final @Name String className, final @Advice.Origin String origin, final @Advice.This Object thiz) {
      if (isEnabled(className, origin))
        filterAdded = JettyAgentIntercept.addFilter(thiz);
    }
  }

  public static class ServletContextAdvice {
    @Advice.OnMethodExit
    public static void exit(final @Name String className, final @Advice.Origin String origin, final @Advice.This Object thiz) {
      if (isEnabled(className, origin))
        filterAdded = ServletContextAgentIntercept.addFilter(thiz);
    }
  }
}
```

Effectively, what I'm trying to do is relay information from the **instance context** of `ServletContextAgentRule` to the **static context** of `JettyAdvice` and `ServletContextAdvice`. Since advice methods are supposed to be static, I cannot figure out a way to get instance state into these methods (without effectively building some kind of external relay mechanism involving class<->instance maps, resulting in copy+pasted code in all subclasses of `AgentRule`). This use-case is being applied to a project that involves [a lot of rules](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-specialagent/tree/master/rule), which is why I'm trying to figure out the most performant and most terse way to do this.

When I try this approach with `Advice.withCustomMapping().bind(...)`, I get an exception from ByteBuddy saying:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler() does not define an index 0
```

Is the purpose of `Advice.withCustomMapping().bind(...)` only to override specific arguments that exist in the method signature? I could not find mention of this in the javadocs, and looking at other examples online, I seem to think that my use-case should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Name { }
```

otherwise Byte Buddy cannot see your annotation and falls back to the default which is an argument with the same index.

Comment: It was as simple as that! Thank you!